# Stratified Sampling based on a column category in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a dataset which has around 280K observations. However bulk of that observation belong to one particular value of a column. Here is the count

```
Category    Count
A   8981
B   6146
C   243369
D   10678
F   4431
G   2421
H   1009
I   7948
```

If you see category C has 243K such record while others have very. I want to down sample the data in such a way that I keep all the records from other category values while only keeping a certain percentage of random records from category 'C'. Like maybe 10% or so. This way I can have proper distribution of data across all these categories.

How to achieve this in postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query selects one random row from the table modified in the way that contains only 10% of rows with `category C` and all rows with other categories:

```
select *
from (
    (select *
    from observations
    where category = 'C'
    order by random()
    limit 243369* 0.1)
    union
    (select *
    from observations
    where category <> 'C')
    ) sub
order by random()
limit 1;
```

Comment: Oh so what you did , you first selected 90% observations where the record was only from C. Then you joined those back to the base table and deleted those observations thereby retaining 10%. Hmm. thats a good approach. Do we have any other straight forward approach which would not require joining. I thought about this too but didn't want to join for just sampling

Comment: And I don't want to delete the base table observations too

Comment: I misunderstood the question, sorry. See the modified answer.

Comment: I don't understand why `limit 1` is added to the end, or the `order by random()` ? From the question it seems as though the goal is to just have a (more) uniformly distributed set of categories, rather than most in cat C.

Comment: @baxx - The OP wanted to get a *sample* of data with the corrected distribution. As the nature of the selection is not defined you can assume it is a random sample. The amount of the sample also is not specified, if you want a larger one increase the limit.